# how can I send file to playbook via USB?

Tags: usb

Is there any way to send files to RIM Playbook via USB? I see device in lsusb (listed as ID 0fca:8020 Research In Motion, Ltd), but device is not mounted in Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry Playbook it seems does not work out of box with USB transfers on Ubuntu but you can still connect via USB Network Share

- Firstly, you need to connect Playbook to your Ubuntu laptop/PC via USB.
- Now, in your Playbook, goto Settings - Storage & Sharing and set USB Connections to Connect to Windows and File Sharing to ON
- Now, goto Settings - About and choose Network from the dropdown menu and write down the IPv4 address.
- Goto your Ubuntu 12.04 desktop now and select Connect to Server option from File menu in the top panel.
- Enter the IP (you noted down)  and change the "Type" item to Windows Share from Public Share. And hit Connect.
- That's it. Blackberry Playbook is now connected to your Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a network shared folder and now you can have all the file transfer you want between Blackberry Playbook and Ubuntu/Linux without a hitch.

Hope this helps and I'm on my phone so I can't post pics but you can visit the link below for illustrations:

[www.techdrivein.com/2012/05/how-to-connect-blackberry-playbook-with.html?m=1](http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/05/how-to-connect-blackberry-playbook-with.html?m=1)